# Can´t access enums in workflow foundation ruleset editor

Tags: c#, enums, workflow-foundation, rule-engine

I would like to create some rules via the ruleset editor. I am loading my DomainObject assembly, in which my objects and in addition some enums are declared.

Here is the ValidationState enum:

```
   public enum ValidationState
   {
      None,
      Passed,
      Failed
   }
```

... and my Person object:

```
   public sealed partial class Person : BaseObject
   {
      ...
   }

   public abstract class BaseObject
   {
      public ValidationState ValidationState { get; set; }

      ...
   }
```

I would like to compare the ValidationState of the Object Person with ValidationState.Failed. But Intellisense is not showing those values.

[image: Ruleset editor]

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try to prepend it with the full namespace, as `this` already has a `ValidationState` property.

Comment: Your damned right... :), I should have seen this. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeCasters comment is the correct answer. As a workaround for not writing the whole namespace (which is not user-friendly) just rename the variables.